# oAuth Client module for PHP

Tags: java, php, magento, oauth, e-commerce

I have to create my own oAuth provider and need that provider to be integrated with PHP application (Magento). I am done with my Provider in Java with spring security but now I am not clear how I can integrate it with magento, Do I need to write a module on the top of PHP oAuth client or anything else, can any buddy help me how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the easiest way to integrate a custom module in magento

http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/

Might help someone....Thanks